# How do I pass a RecyclerView item in the second Activity to the previous Activity in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities - A and B

A- `Detail Activity` where details get updated

B- A `Search Activity` or `Fragment` where the user selects an item from a list of items and  the selected item is reflected in Activity A

Can anyone suggest a good and efficient way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

and find findViewHolderforLayoutPosition, findViewHolderForAdapterPosition

Comment: while starting Actviity B use startActivityForResult() and get your result back in Actviity A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(ContentItem item);
}
```

Above code in your adapter

```
private final List<ContentItem> items;
private final OnItemClickListener listener;

public ContentAdapter(List<ContentItem> items, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.items = items;
    this.listener = listener;
}



@Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(items.get(position), listener);
}


public void bind(final ContentItem item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
    ...
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(item);
        }
    });
}


// in your Activity 

recycler.setAdapter(new ContentAdapter(items, new ContentAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override public void onItemClick(ContentItem item) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("key","value");
        startActivity(i)
    }
}));
```

[read more](https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/)

Answer (score 0):

How about the onActivityResult?

Check this one http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/08/return-result-to-onactivityresult.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using B as a fragment you can use an interface to communicate between your fragment and activity.Any changes in the fragment can be reflected back in your parent activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data from one Activity to another using intent. Just put the data in bundle or extra when you are calling an intent to navigate through one Activity to another. Like this

```
Intent asd = new Intent(getApplicationContext, ActivityA.class);
asd.putExtra(strName, STRING_I_NEED);
startActitvity(asd);
```

And to get data in `ActivityA`,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras == null) {
     newString= null;
} else {
     newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two way of doing this

1. If you wanna just need to pass the data from A to B activity and
   move forward then you can use the [serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) object and pass
   it along with the intent and afterwards if you return back on the A
   again then in onResume method you can call the datasource again for
   the data. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)
2. You can startActivityForResult(); in activity A and that will starts
   B Activity and after returning from the B it will automatically
   trigger onActivityResult(); [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)